# Get client session id from Keycloak access token

Tags: javascript, openid-connect, keycloak

In reference to Keycloak's [documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/server_development/topics/identity-brokering/account-linking.html) for account linking, I need to fetch **user session id** and **client session id** from the access token.

However, I only find something they call `session_state` on the token which apparently is the same as `sessionId` by looking at their [javascript adapter source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-js-bower/blob/1734987d1e39310eab466aa8727934a504f7a49f/dist/keycloak.js#L672).

I reckon that this is the **user session id** they are referring to? If so, where do I find this so called **client session id**?

Comment: Got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yup! Turned out it as the client id. So something like this should work:

Extract user session id and client session id ("aud" is the client id) from access token:

`const { session_state, aud } = 
JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(accessToken.split('.')
[1]))))`

Create base64 hash:

`Base64.stringify(sha256(nonce + session_state + aud + 'facebookOrWhatever'))`

You also need make the resulting base64 encoded hash url friendly (i.e. '+' and '/' are replaced with '-' and '_' also remove any trailing '=' characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out it as the client id. So something like this should work:

Extract user session id and client session id ("aud" is the client id) from access token:

```
const { session_state, aud } = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(accessToken.split(‌​'.') [1]))))
```

Create base64 hash:

```
Base64.stringify(sha256(nonce + session_state + aud + 'facebookOrWhatever'))
```

You also need make the resulting base64 encoded hash url friendly (i.e. '+' and '/' are replaced with '-' and '_' also remove any trailing '=' characters)